# Usage of "so that" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I wrote this sentence

> Some of the rules could be common to many websites. Therefore, the rulesets are organized in a hierarchical fashion/structure **(in which or so that ?)** a ruleset can be derived from a more general ruleset.

As I used "can be" I suspect that I should use "so that"?!

Comment: Another option (which I think I would use) is *in such a way that*. The phrase can be shorten as *such that* but may be frowned upon by some readers.

Comment: Methinks, the difference between "*so that*" and "*such that*" shows in what they address in the previous clause.  "*So that*" would refer to "*organized*", and "*such that*" would refer to "*fashion/structure*".

Answer (score 2):

Write:

> Therefore, the rulesets are organized in a hierarchical fashion/structure **such that** a ruleset can be derived from a more general ruleset.

Why:

I don't know. As a native English speaker, it's difficult to describe *why*. It just comes from experience. Like so many things in English, unfortunately, rules don't really apply as much as patterns of common usage.